# I'm looking for a specialized word for prisoner's behaviour in jail

Tags: word-request

Is there any special word that can be used instead of good behaviour in this context?

> Some prisoners deserve probations for behaving well during
> imprisonment, while some others have to be ensnared consistently due
> to lack of good **behaviour**.

I am looking for a specialized word that exactly describes how a prisoner behaves in jail, and judicial officials make decision on the conditions the prisoner should serve its jail based on this behaviours.

Comment: "conduct" and "misconduct" are often used in such contexts.

Comment: I don't think that **ensnared** is the right word to use in this sentence, because it relates to the transition from free to captive, rather than to remaining captive. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ensnare

Comment: "Good behavio(u)r" or "good conduct" are common. You should specify where in the world you're talking about, as legal and penal systems will have specific terminology (terms like "time off for good behavior" aren't real legal concepts everywhere).